# Unable to use BenchmarkDotNet on WSL2: "Access to the path '/mnt/c/DumpStack.log.tmp' is denied."

Tags: f#, wsl-2, benchmarkdotnet

I'm playing with the performance chapter from the (excellent) book [Stylish F#: Crafting Elegant Functional Code for .NET and .NET Core](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/stylish-f-crafting/9781484240007/).

Here is a basic [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) benchmark:

```ml
open BenchmarkDotNet.Running
open BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes

module Dummy =
    let slowFunction () =
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 100
        99

    let fastFunction () =
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 10
        99

module Harness =
    [<MemoryDiagnoser>]
    type Harness() =
        [<Benchmark>]
        member _.Old() = Dummy.slowFunction ()

        [<Benchmark>]
        member _.New() = Dummy.fastFunction ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let run _ =
    BenchmarkRunner.Run<Harness.Harness>()
    |> printfn "%A"
    0
```

On my WSL2 Linux Ubuntu 20.04, after `dotnet -c release` (I truncated the end):

```
// Validating benchmarks:
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Start   *****
// ***** Found 2 benchmark(s) in total *****
// ***** Building 1 exe(s) in Parallel: Start   *****
// ***** Done, took 00:00:00 (0.13 sec)   *****
// Found 2 benchmarks:
//   Harness.Old: DefaultJob
//   Harness.New: DefaultJob

// Generate Exception: Access to the path '/mnt/c/DumpStack.log.tmp' is denied.

// BenchmarkDotNet has failed to build the auto-generated boilerplate code.
// It can be found in /mnt/c/data/dev/fsharp-lab/Stylish-FSharp6/bin/release/net6.0/c456e559-bdf2-4a24-858d-b423379f42c9
// Please follow the troubleshooting guide: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/troubleshooting.html
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Finish  *****
```

My understanding is that neither my WSL2 user (nor root) can read the Dump stack logging from Windows 11:

- => Is it possible to grant access to these files (at the expense of lower security, I guess)?
- => Is BenchmarkDotNet even supposed to work on WSL2?